# ReactJS, React-Router: Calling parent function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on a React App, trying to call a parent method from a child component, some code of the parent component below:

```
    class NavigationBar extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={isLoggedIn: false};
      }

      updateLoginState(){
        alert("Login from NavigationBar");
      }

      GetBar() {
          //const isLoggedIn = this.props.isLoggedIn;
          if (false){   //isLoggedIn
            return this.UserNavBar();
          }
          return this.StrangerNavBar();
      }

      StrangerNavBar(){
        return (

          <div>
            <HashRouter>    
              <div>
              {/* ... */}     
                <div className="content">
                  <Route exact path="/LoginCC" loginUpdate={this.updateLoginState} component={LoginCC} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </HashRouter>
          </div>    
      );
      }


    render() {
      return (
        this.GetBar()
      );
    }

  }

  export default NavigationBar;
```

This component is supposed to redirect the user to different content pages based on whether or not he is logged in, using a `Router`. If a button is clicked in `LoginCC.js` the method `updateLoginState` should be invoked which just displays a message for now. The child content page `LoginCC.js` looks as follows:

```
class LoginCC extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {isLoggedIn: false};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HashRouter>
          {/* ... */}       
              <Button variant="primary" size="lg" block onClick={this.props.loginUpdate}>
                Log in
              </Button> 
          {/* ... */}    
        </HashRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginCC;
```

I passed the method reference as a prop to `LoginCC` when rendering this component using the `Router`, so a message should pop up if I press the button, but nothing happens.

Am I passing the prop incorrectly or something else I've missed? I'm new to React so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Route` doesn't pass any custom props to components. You should use other method to pass functions.

One of solutions is:

```
<Route exact path="/LoginCC" render={
    props => <LoginCC {...props} loginUpdate={this.updateLoginState}/>
} />
```

Note that `updateLoginState` will not get `this` when called. You should either `bind` it or declare it as an arrow function to get the correct `this`.

Also check the [Context documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks for the solution and pointer! :)